# Login page sql databaseand blank page

Tags: php, sql

I have a USER Table
user ISA admin
user ISA member

Registration to User table works fine...
I am trying to create a login page that creates a session.. when I submit username and password I receive a white screen. My 3 files are below, cananyone see any errors as to why this will not allow a login? Just get a blank page?

**Login.php**

```
    <table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78">Username</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="294"><input name="username" type="text" id="username"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="password" type="text" id="password"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Checklogin.php**

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; 
$username="root"; 
$password=""; 
$db_name="membersappdb"; 
$tbl_name="users"; 

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "membersappdb") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
echo "Connected to database";

$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){

session_register("username");
session_register("password");
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

**LoginSucess**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(username)){
header("location:login.php");
}
?>

<html>
<body>
Login Successful
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you use session_register instead of $_SESSION['']
also you miss session_start in your checklogin.php page.

Comment: session_is_registered has been deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0 and removed in PHP 5.4.0.

Comment: session_is_registered --> Warning

This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.

Comment: `mysqli_connect()` and `mysql_query()` do not mix

Answer (score 0):

This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0, Check your PHP version.

Make sure you have session_start(), as just removing session_register() and relying on the $_SESSION assignment won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    session_register() is deprecated in and after PHP 5.3 .
 Instead use $_SESSION['var'] = "value" to set variables.
 In Checklogin.php change
 session_register("username") to $_SESSIOn['username'] = $username
 and 
 session_register("password") to $_SESSIOn['password'] = $password .

    In LoginSucess.php change
     if(!session_is_registered(username)){
    header("location:login.php");
    }

    to

    if(!$_SESSION['username']){
    header("location:login.php");
    }

    Cheers!
```

Answer (score 0):

If your query is working fine and getting result by login credentials, then you just need to rename your file `login_success.php` name to `LoginSuccess.php`.

Currently

```
header("location:login_success.php");
```

Rename to

```
header("location:LoginSuccess.php");
```

Try out this, Best Luck